# "No matching function call to..." for template function

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to do a binary search template, when I run it using the primitive "int" the code runs fine but when I run it with "string" I get the error

"No matching function call to binary_search_template"

Why does it work with ints but not strings?

Here is the code

```
main{
 std::vector<string> e;
    e.push_back("a");
    e.push_back("b");
    e.push_back("c");

int index = binary_search_template(e, 0, d.size()-1.0, "a"); //error for strings but not ints

}
```

header file

```
template<typename T>
int binary_search_template(std::vector<T>& a, int from, int to, T value);

template<typename T>
int binary_search_template(std::vector<T>& a, int from, int to, T value)
{
    if (from > to) {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (to + from)/2;

    if (a[mid] == value ) {
        return mid;
    }else if (a[mid] < value) {
        return binary_search_template(a, mid+1, to, value);
    }else {
        return binary_search_template(a, from, mid, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `return binary_search_template<T>(a, mid+1, to, value);`

Comment: No error is shown on that line of code, only when I call it from main and use a string but for ints it seems to work fine

Comment: I think it is because it cannot deduce the template argument T as std::string from the value "a". It's probably deducing `const char*` and getting confused. So you could either explicitly name the template param or use `std::string('a')` as final argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler sees two candidates for the type `T` when you use a `std::vector<std::string>` and a string literal:

1. `std::string`
2. `char const*`

You'll need to make up you mind, e.g., by passing the argument as `std::string("a")`. Alternatively you could use an additional template parameter for the last argument.